# Combined authentication in SharePoint online: Office Graph and SPO

Tags: angularjs, adal, office365api

Learning Angular, so please assume I know nothing (it's what I assume).

Developing an application hosted on SharePoint online. Therefore, it is a given that the user accessing the application is already authenticated versus Office 365. This is working, and my application has access to SharePoint functions via the SharePoint REST API.

For the next step, I want to access the Office Graph. I know and understand that I have to authenticate differently versus Azure AD. I have configured an example based on [this code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp) and have it working. I am now trying to transplant this code to my own application. I have configured a new application in Azure AD to provision the URI of the SPO site hosting the application.

My goal is to achieve a situation where the current user is consumed by ADAL, since the user is already logged in. Different from the mentioned example, I am trying to achieve this without using routing. I am attempting to run the following code:

```
var appModule = angular.module("appModule", ["AdalAngular"]);
appModule.config(["$httpProvider", "adalAuthenticationServiceProvider",
function($httpProvider, adalProvider) {
var adalConfig = {          
instance: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
tenant: "<ourtenantname>.onmicrosoft.com",
clientId: "<client id from Azure AD>",
endpoints: {"https://graph.microsoft.com/": "https://graph.microsoft.com"},
cacheLocation: "localStorage"
};
adalProvider.init(adalConfig, $httpProvider);
}
]);
```

When I run this, console shows "The returned id_token is not parseable". I have verified that the Azure AD configuration is correct (including implicit flow) as I can use it elsewhere. I'm pretty much lost. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps my answer is no longer relevant, but still. But I ran into a similar problem with Angular and AD/Graph from microsoft.
[Please read this step again](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp#step-3--enable-the-oauth2-implicit-grant-for-your-application) You need to enable oAuth2.0 in you App in Azure. Please check your App manifest in azure.